# Using asynchronous values synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have data for tax rates stored in the database (to allow updating of tax rates). In javascript, all database operations are asynchronous, which means that I have to use a promise or callback to access the result of the query. Is there a way to retrieve the values from the database in one module, and use those values in a synchronous fashion in other modules?

I am asking this because it is a pain to render components based on promise values in react. Thanks!

Comment: It's the correct way to do it and for good reason - I suggest using promises and getting used to them. Then they will no longer be a pain :)

Comment: a moments thought and you would realise how impossible `Using asynchronous values synchronously` is

Comment: There are two types of, and those that don't. javascript coders, those that understand asyncrhonous code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a function, you can now use the `async` and `await` keywords to work with promises in a synchronous-feeling way. However, you can't actually turn an asynchronous action into a totally normal synchronous function that immediately returns a value, no (without doing crazy things you wouldn't want to do).

To render a component based on a promised value in React, make space in `this.state` for the value, refer to `this.state.yourValue` in the `render()` method, and then call for the promise in `componentDidMount()`, updating the state when it's ready. [Here's a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/buLbm3c4/).